# Python serial read corrupting print statements

Tags: python, pyserial

I have this bizarre situation where reading from a serial port is appearing to corrupt calls to `print`. This code:

```py
        ser = serial.Serial('COM13', 115200, timeout=5)
        ser.reset_input_buffer()
        ser.reset_output_buffer()

        ser.write("stat\n".encode('utf-8'))
        ser.flush()

        for i in range(10):
            print(f"read: <{self.ser.read(10).decode('utf-8')}>")
```

outputs

```
>ead: <s
read: <
>
read: <>
read: <>
read: <>
...
```

How can that first '>' be printed by python the first time instead of the `r` of `read`?!

If I replace the serial calls with just a string, the behaviour is no longer seen .

Comment: @TurePålsson ahh that's it, seeing the repr there's some escape sequences in there. Feel free to post as an answer and I'll accept :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wild guess is that you’re getting a “carriage return” character (ASCII 13) from the serial port — that would cause the terminal to jump back to the leftmost position. Try adding a `!r` to the end of the `{}` block in the f-string, so that it prints the repr of the string (or just omit the `.decode(...)` so that the undecoded byte array gets printed); that should make it obvious if there are any unprintables in there.